# Can there be setup.py files for python subpackages?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, setup.py, python-packaging

I saw that scipy had setup.py files inside its sub packages. What do these setup.py files do? Is it used to build the sub packages?

Is there any documentation or a webpage where this is explained or like a tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you don't need any additional setup scripts to build the distribution. SciPy requires additional setup scripts mainly to reduce the amount of subpackage-specific boilerplate configuration code. The setup scripts in SciPy subpackages are mainly used for configuration preparation when building the whole distribution - the building and packaging still being done from the root setup script. As described in [NumPy Distutils - Users Guide](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/DISTUTILS.rst.txt):

> #### Requirements for SciPy packages
>
> SciPy consists of Python packages, called SciPy packages, that are
>   available to Python users via the `scipy` namespace. Each SciPy package
>   may contain other SciPy packages. And so on. Therefore, the SciPy
>   directory tree is a tree of packages with arbitrary depth and width.
>   Any SciPy package may depend on NumPy packages but the dependence on other
>   SciPy packages should be kept minimal or zero.
>
> A SciPy package contains, in addition to its sources, the following
>   files and directories:
>
> - `setup.py` --- building script
> - `__init__.py` --- package initializer
> - `tests/` --- directory of unittests
>
> Their contents are described below.
>
> #### The `setup.py` file
>
> In order to add a Python package to SciPy, its build script (`setup.py`)
>   must meet certain requirements. The most important requirement is that the
>   package define a `configuration(parent_package='',top_path=None)` function
>   which returns a dictionary suitable for passing to
>   `numpy.distutils.core.setup(..)`. To simplify the construction of
>   this dictionary, `numpy.distutils.misc_util` provides the
>   `Configuration` class, described below.
>
> #### SciPy pure Python package example
>
> Below is an example of a minimal `setup.py` file for a pure SciPy package
>
> ```
>  #!/usr/bin/env python
>  def configuration(parent_package='',top_path=None):
>      from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration
>      config = Configuration('mypackage',parent_package,top_path)
>      return config
>
>  if __name__ == "__main__":
>      from numpy.distutils.core import setup
>      #setup(**configuration(top_path='').todict())
>      setup(configuration=configuration)
> ```